# How to test a dropdown-toggle operation in angular 2 testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to test the dropdown-toggle function. But I could not manage to get it to work. I have also imported `BsDropdownModule` to the spec file.
Note: I'm using ngx-bootstrap.

Here's what I tried:

**Html:**

```
<div class="btnBox" dropdown placement="bottom right">
    <button class="btnIcon dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle>
    </button>
    <ul class="btnOptionBox dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *dropdownMenu>
       <li class="iconBtn" (click)="someFun()" type="button"><span>Edit</span></li>
       <li class="iconBtn" (click)="someFun1()" type="button"><span>Delete</span></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

**Test Spec:**

```
it("Should show options when toggle option is clicked",() => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     let toggleButton = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('[dropdownToggle]'));
     toggleButton[0].nativeElement.click();
     fixture.detectChanges();
     /*Unable to access li tag directly. That's why I have used it's parent*/
     let list = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('div.ellipsisBox'));  
     console.log(list[0]); /*Shows the list in the children array*/
     console.log(list[0].children);  /*Doesn't show the list*/
});
```

Can anyone suggest the right way to do it?

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how did you import the BsDropdownModule in your spec. When I do that, it gives me a bunch of static injector errors. I tried with your solution but I'm facing the same problem where even after clicking the button, the ul is not there in the dom.

Comment: Have you tried adding FormsModule instead? Are you getting injector errors for BsDropdownModule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue. It was just a silly mistake. The data in the list is populated by an **asynchronous process**. So I was supposed to use `fakeAsync` and `tick()` after clicking the dropdown button. The view was updated before the data was populated into the list. That caused the problem. Here's the fixed code:

```
it("Should show options when toggle option is clicked",fakeAsync(() => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     let toggleButton = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('[dropdownToggle]'));
     toggleButton[0].nativeElement.click();
     tick();
     fixture.detectChanges();
     let list = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('ul.btnOptionBox'));  
     console.log(list[0]);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me. Not sure if this is a silly mistake – I think knowing and remembering when you have to use fakeAsync / tick is not easy.

Comment: I don't see your expectations though, Don't you need to have an expectation for this test?

Comment: @Girum There must be expectations, I just haven't included it since it isn't relevant to explain my issue.

Comment: Thanks Sanju, Got it, your example is great though.

Comment: Hi, @Sanju can I use async await in this case, After clicking on dropdown? like this `await SleepForASecond(0)`

This is my code inside SleepForASecond

`static sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  static async SleepForASecond(ms) {
    await this.sleep(ms);
  }`