How do I unit a .dropdown-toggle or .dropdown rendering in Angular with Jasmine?
I'm attempting to test a button.btn.dropdown-toggle element created with bootstrap 5. When the Angular project is served, clicking the button changes its aria-expanded attribute from false to true and it gains the class show. While the button does not have a (click) handler, clicking the button toggles the dropdown render.
I'm writing one unit test that attempts to see if the dropdown list renders by expecting the aria-expanded attribute, but it does not change in the midst of the test nor does the show class appear.
The initial template and unit test:
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="strategySelectionMenu" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        {{stratSelection}}
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <div *ngFor="let strategy of presetStrats">
            <li><button class="dropdown-item" (click)="stratSelection = strategy.name">{{strategy.name}}</button></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

it('should show strategy dropdown only after clicking the dropdown button', () => {
    const strategyDropDown = root.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').item(0) as HTMLDivElement;
    expect(strategyDropDown).toBeDefined();
    
    let stratSelectButton = strategyDropDown.getElementsByTagName('button').namedItem('strategySelectionMenu') as HTMLButtonElement;
    expect(stratSelectButton.ariaExpanded).toEqual('false');

    stratSelectButton.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(stratSelectButton.ariaExpanded).toEqual('true');
});

I've attempted the strategy listed in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723667/13352424 as well as setTimeout() in place of tick(), but it did not change the outcome.
I've also refactored the test to use the debugElement instead of the nativeElement and the test proceeds properly until the last expect.
Assuming that .click() was the issue, I tried dispatchEvent() with various events to no change in outcome.
Is there a proper way to test that a dropdown menu is properly rendered from a click event?
==
Since posing the question, I've attempted to call .click() on both the surrounding div.dropdown as well as on the ul.dropdown-menu within the unit test. Neither worked out for solving this issue, so "clicking" within the unit test must not be the way to approach this matter.
==-==
I'm not too sure of the efficacy of using fakesync() in conjunction with tick() and fixture.detectChanges(), but it can't hurt to leave it in. The current strategy, that doesn't work, utilized the Dropdown type from bootstrap. I define the surrounding div as such and spy on its show() method:
const strategyDropDown = root.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').item(0) as HTMLDivElement;
    const dropdownInstance = Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(strategyDropDown) as Dropdown;

    spyOn(dropdownInstance, 'show');

    let stratSelectButton = strategyDropDown.getElementsByTagName('button').namedItem('strategySelectionMenu') as HTMLButtonElement;
    expect(stratSelectButton.ariaExpanded).toEqual('false');
    expect(stratSelectButton.classList.contains('show')).toBeFalse();

    strategyDropDown.click();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(dropdownInstance.show).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(stratSelectButton.classList.contains('show')).toBeTrue();
    expect(stratSelectButton.ariaExpanded).toEqual('true');

Based on Bootstrap documentation, a Dropdown's show() method is called when the dropdown list is rendered or unrendered.
None of the following expectations returned true, so there is still an issue with calling click() on the DOM object.
==-==-==
When utilizing breakpoints in the case block, a barebones webpage is created for debugging my component. In this webpage, the dropdown is not rendered as you would see it on my website; there is the button that renders the dropdown list, and a list of buttons below it that represent the list items. Is there a way to "unit test" that the front end renders properly, or is this not something that can be handled that way?
